# Spring Integration FTP Outbound Gateway console output

Tags: spring, spring-integration

In the Spring Integration documentation example for ftp outbound gateway with Java configuration (16.8.1), how do I log the payload of the reply channel to the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `WireTap` `@Bean` and wire its `MessageChannel` to a `LoggingHandler`.

Add the wire tap as a `ChannelInterceptor` to the gateway output channel.

Or, use the `.wiretap()` when using the Java DSL.

[Documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-wiretap).

**EDIT**

Java Config:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So49308064Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So49308064Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner (Gate gate) {
        return args -> {
            List<String> list = gate.list("foo");
            System.out.println("Result:" + list);
        };
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "ftpLS")
    @Bean
    public FtpOutboundGateway getGW() {
        FtpOutboundGateway gateway = new FtpOutboundGateway(sf(), "ls", "payload");
        gateway.setOption(Option.NAME_ONLY);
        gateway.setOutputChannelName("results");
        return gateway;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel results() {
        DirectChannel channel = new DirectChannel();
        channel.addInterceptor(tap());
        return channel;
    }

    @Bean
    public WireTap tap() {
        return new WireTap("logging");
    }

    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "logging")
    @Bean
    public LoggingHandler logger() {
        LoggingHandler logger = new LoggingHandler(Level.INFO);
        logger.setLogExpressionString("'Files:' + payload");
        return logger;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf() {
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost("...");
        sf.setUsername("...");
        sf.setPassword("...");
        return sf;
    }

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "ftpLS", defaultReplyChannel = "results")
    public interface Gate {

        List<String> list(String directory);

    }

}
```

.

```
2018-03-29 09:04:20.383  INFO 15158 --- [           main] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   
             : Files:bar.tx,bar.txt,baz.txt
Result:[bar.tx, bar.txt, baz.txt]
```

Java DSL:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So49308064Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So49308064Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner (Gate gate) {
        return args -> {
            List<String> list = gate.list("foo");
            System.out.println("Result:" + list);
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() {
        return f -> f
                .handle((Ftp.outboundGateway(sf(), "ls", "payload").options(Option.NAME_ONLY)))
                .log(Level.INFO, "lsResult", "payload")
                .bridge(); // needed, otherwise log ends the flow.
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf() {
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        sf.setHost("...");
        sf.setUsername("...");
        sf.setPassword("...");
        return sf;
    }

    @MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "flow.input")
    public interface Gate {

        List<String> list(String directory);

    }

}
```

.

```
2018-03-29 09:12:28.991  INFO 16638 --- [           main] lsResult                                 
                 : [bar.tx, bar.txt, baz.txt]
Result:[bar.tx, bar.txt, baz.txt]
```

Comment: Gary: Couldn't figure out how to write these. Would be grateful if you give code snippets.

Comment: Great, this code works for me. In your output I see multiple files listed. But, I get only one file name, though there are multiple files on the ftp server. I am using Apache FtpServer in stand alone mode and my computer is Windows 8.

Comment: What you are describing makes no sense; what do you see with a command line FTP client and `ls`? That is all that this code is doing. Maybe try turning on debug logging on the server.

Comment: Sorry, my bad (luck & attention).  Apache FTP server users.properties has
`ftpserver.user.anonymous.homedirectory=./res/home`
In `res\home`, there is a README.txt file and it's the only file. So the listing (ls) is right.

I was checking the Apache FTP server installation folder from where I started the server. In this folder, there is a README.txt along with other files and I was thinking that they were not getting listed.